# How to re-arrange the data order of a table?

Tags: php, html, database

I have already uploaded my website to the internet. But I need to change the order of entering data to my table. The new records appear at the bottom of the table instead i need it to be at the top. How can I do this?

Comment: apply order by in your query

Comment: You will need to have create a column with some sequential incrementing integer *(Like: id: 1, 2, 3,...)* And then use `Order By Desc`

Answer (score 0):

Please use sort by `(id)` OR

When You have updated or created date then use sort by `(created or updated)` date. That will solve your problem.

Sort By means `order by` in your query

For Example :

```
ORDER BY column_name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

to display the latest on the top, you need to **ORDER** your results set by descending order.

But to order by descending order ( To get the latest on the top ) you need to have a column in your table with Integer value  ( probably your primary key ) or **Date**.

Here is an example.

Assume I'm having a table in my DB called, Events and here is the structure of the table

[image]

Now i'm going to display the results without ordering, which means now the id=7 result should display on the top. Here is the php code for that

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<?php
require_once('../DB/connect.php');
$result4= mysql_query("SELECT * from events  ");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
$e_id=$row['id'];
$e_name=$row['ename'];
echo'<tr><td> <img src="../imgs/settings/event5.png" class="img-responsive"></td><td><b>'.$e_name.'</b> </td>';
echo'<td><a button type="button" href="#'.$e_id.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"> EDIT  </a>

</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> DELETE  </button>
</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Now the above code will give me a result like this.

[image]

you can see my older record display on the top.

Now I'm going to change my sql query a bit to display the latest/newest record on the top.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<?php
require_once('../DB/connect.php');
$result4= mysql_query("SELECT * from events ORDER by id DESC  ");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
$e_id=$row['id'];
$e_name=$row['ename'];
echo'<tr><td> <img src="../imgs/settings/event5.png" class="img-responsive"></td><td><b>'.$e_name.'</b> </td>';
echo'<td><a button type="button" href="#'.$e_id.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"> EDIT  </a>

</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> DELETE  </button>
</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

so the above code will give me a result like this,

[image]

Like that, you can display the latest result on the top by using **ORDER BY column_name DESC**